# If f is monotone on a closed interval then it is absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

How do I prove that if a function f is monotone on a closed interval then it is absolutely continuous, I know that if it is monotone that it has bounded variation, but that doesn't imply that $$\sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i))|<\epsilon$$ for all $\epsilon>0$ it only implies that this sum is finite.

Comment: What happens if $f=0$ on $[0,1)$ and $ f(1)=1?$

Comment: Even a continuous monotone function need not be absolutely continuous, see the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)

Comment: Oh, so the statement isn't actually true.